# Opencart -> Clean URLS

Tags: url, seo, clean-urls, opencart

I am using Opencart  1.4.9.4  is there a way that I can change my urls from the query string to category/product?

Example:

Current:

```
index.php?route=product/category&path=57
```

Wanted:

`domain.co.nz/animals/monkey.php`

I have tried google but I have been getting mixed answers with the seo_urls.php and .htacess documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.4.X doesn't have a URL class, so unfortunately not. 1.5.X supports this however

Answer (score 2):

OpenCart does support SEO friendly URLs by default. So you don't have to add a module or modify the code for that. 
All you need to do is to locate the file .htaccess.txt under the home folder of your website and rename it to .htaccess and also enable the SEO Friendly URLs option from your admin control panel. 
After you've done all that, you can set the "SEO Keyword" for your products by editing them.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, in recent versions it is supported.

But Be aware of default Opencart SEO friendly URLs.

For example, you can have domain.co.nz/animals/monkey.php urls.
But product monkey belongs to several categories. So you have:
- domain.co.nz/animals/monkey.php 
- domain.co.nz/primates/monkey.php

And both links point to the same product page. It will **produce duplicates in Google**. And products HTML doesn't even contain canonical meta tags.

No so friendly URLs :)